# How can I set the start and end calendar dates in dojox.widget.calendar?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How can I set the start and end calendar dates in `dojox.widget.calendar`?

I'm trying to restrict the user from navigating outside those dates.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting the max and min dates?

See the example below

```
<div maxlength="12" 
data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
data-dojo-props="required: true, constraints:{min:'1880-01-01', 
    max: '2020-01-01'}, popupClass: 'dojox.widget.Calendar'">
```